# How to cut and paste, but if file exists then proceed with delete

Tags: windows, cut-and-paste

When we cut and paste, it appears that it is essentially a short cut for move, and if the move is successful, delete the original

If the file already exists in the destination location, Windows pops up a box and asks if I want to move it any way (with a tweak to the file name) or do not copy.

At this point, I remain with a manual step of deleting the file.

Is there a way to make Windows continue to the delete step regardless of whether I choose "copy" or "do not copy"

[image]